# Login between sites not linked? Or what am I doing wrong?

Tags: support

I just discovered all of the social features of the site. More importantly I just discovered sister sites like

android.stackexchange
gaming.stackexchange
unix.stackexchange

When I went to android.stackexchange, it shows the Login link instead of my Username, on the top mid/right. So I clicked Login and chose to use my SE account. However it is not accepting my email address as valid even though my email is properly listed on my profile here.

I tried both Propercase@mailserver.com and lowercase@mailserver.com to make sure it wasn't a capitalization issue. Neither works -- the emails I just listed are not my real email by the way. :-)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Sorry for not clarifying. What I'm trying to do is to sign up using my Stack Exchange account. It isn't accepting the login that I use on ServerFault, though.

Answer (score 2):

Did you sign up using the Stack Exchange account? It's a bit ambiguous but that means to use StackExhange as your OpenID Provider.

If you logged into your first site as say, google, then you have to consistently use that all over the network.

Comment: ...or associate all the OpenIDs you've collected over the years with your Stack Exchange account :)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. What I'm trying to do is to sign up using my Stack Exchange account. It isn't accepting the login that I use on ServerFault, though.

Comment: I get it now. It wasn't very obvious but until I create a Stack Exchange account, my ServerFault account is separate. I just created the StackExchange account and all of my info transferred.

Comment: Voretaq, your answer got me what I needed. Please add it as an answer rather than a comment so I can accept it. Thanks.